# PHP stopped working after I upgraded

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Windows install with Apache. I'm **not** using WAMP.

I just upgraded from 5.2.3 to 5.3.0. After I installed it (msi) I restarted the server but php isn't working. I looked at the httpd file and noticed that the php loadmodule is not there anymore. Can someone offer a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the follow in my httpd.conf file.

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp2/bin/php/php5.3.0/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

(this is for wampserver install)

Just change the path to where you installed php and you should be good.

Comment: Hey Samuel, I'll give this a try now and be right back. Thanks!

Comment: Samuel, I just searched the entire hard drive and don't have that dll anywhere.

Comment: look in c:\Program Files\PHP for php5.dll I think that is the file you need.

Comment: Hey Samuel, I tried using that file too but nothing. I just found a bug report on the PHP site regarding that file accidentally being excluded from the MSI.

Comment: It looks like the fix is to download the VC9 threaded version. I downloaded the non-threaded version so we'll see how that goes. :/

Comment: Yep.. That works great. All I needed to do was download the threaded version. Thanks for all the help Samuel!